# Joomla Extension for beer tasting list?

Tags: list, joomla, tabular

I'm running a website where home beer brewers are posting their beer tasting experiences. 
Something like this:

```
Beer name = Winter Season
Beer Color = Dark red
Beer taste = Fruity with apple
Brew Date = 01/08/2013
Tast Date = 01/01/2014
....
```

Does an extension exist where users can **post** their **information in a list**?

Does an extension exist where users can **compare** their **information with other users** in one **table**? --> A kind of worksheet?

```
User name = Brewer 1          | Brewer 2      | Brewer 3      |
Beer name = Winter Season     | Winter Season | Winter Season |
Beer Color = Dark red         | Dark brown    | Dark          |
Beer taste = Fruity with apple| Ripe banana   | Ripe grapes   |
Brew Date = 01/08/2013        | 01/08/2013    | 01/08/2013    | 
Tast Date = 01/01/2014        | 01/02/2014    | 01/08/2014    |
....
```

Comment: You should probably use on of the form builder extensions http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There probably isn't an extension that does this but you could easily use a form and table builder tool to accomplish it. I would highly recommend you use "fabrik'.

http://fabrikar.com/features

This tool will allow you to create forms and lists with all the various form elements you need.

An alternative to this is to use a CCK like Zoo or K2. There's some other options to like using a plugin to override Joomla's core content component and add these fields. All of these methods will accomplish your goal. The path of least resistance imho is Fabrik or a CCK. The other options require rolling out a fair amount of custom code.

Comment: This looks promising!